# How to run non-thread-safe code concurrently?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, multiprocessing

I'm currently using a C library which has no specification on thread-safety. There are some file static non-const variables in the library's source code, and so I believe it's not thread-safe.

However, I want to run it concurrently to improve the throughput. How can I do that?

---

Edit:
1) I don't want any solution that makes it serial, because my goad is to improve the throughput.
2) I want to limit the discussion on the basis of not modifying the library code, except that it can be done very easily. I may need to use tens of libraries. To modify every library is simply not feasible.

I'd like to add  @JonChesterfield's comment of "concurrency need not imply threads" and "understanding an api instead of the code is broadly the point of a library" here. Thank you for fully understand my need!

Comment: Just serialize calls to the library, i.e. while one part of the program is using the library, the other part can't. Simplest way is to use a mutex. Note that this means you don't run the code concurrently to itself, only perhaps to other code.

Comment: Understand the code to modify it to support concurrency

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt That's definitely not what I want. The ultimate goal is to improve throughtput! By the way, I don't understand why the 'c++' tag is deleted from my question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Modifying the code is not feasible. The code maybe too complex. And why did you deleted the 'c++' tag?

Comment: In addition to the good suggestions made here already, I'd add that you could also replace the library with something similar that is thread-safe. Lastly, one of the easiest modifications you could make is to convert shared objects to thread-local objects.

Comment: The C++ tag doesn't belong there because you have no C++ question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Can I say that if I simply replace all the file static variables to thread local, the library is guaranteed to be thread-safe?

Comment: Concurrency is complex. If you don't want to understand it because it's too hard for you, then concurrency is not for you. Randomly changing variable lifetime and scope seems unlikely to be productive.

Comment: Thread-safety isn't achieved by accident.  If the code is not thread-safe, you can't use it with multiple threads accessing the code at one time.  And if the variables are used to retain state between calls (think `strtok()` or `localtime()`, for example), you have to control access over a larger scope than just the function call.  There isn't a simple magic bullet that fixes the problems; you have to work hard, or accept the limitations imposed by the code's lack of thread safety (which limits the available concurrency).

Comment: If everything that was before shared between threads is now separated, different threads can't interact. However, they can neither interact in a bad way (collide) nor in a good way (communicate). This may not be all that is required to make the code thread-safe though. Converting code to be thread-safe is not a trivial exercise, you will have to understand what you're doing.

Comment: Please don't edit the question telling us not to answer in a specific way. Let us be the judge of what we think the answer is. If it's not what you hope for then maybe you need to recalibrate. It's fine though to state broad goals, but statements like "don't answer suggesting mutex or changing library" is not going to help anyone.

Comment: Why the focus on shared address space threads here? The request is concurrency for throughput, so the solution is probably multiple processes.

Comment: @Jon I don't see how you can say that with confidence given how little information is available to us. I contend that giving such suggestions is actually poor advice. It suggests that it is possible to design a concurrent program without knowing anything about what it does.

Comment: @David Heffernan I'm pattern matching against the common solutions for parallelising legacy code. Without editing the thread-unsafe code, multiprocess or serial are pretty much all the options.

Comment: @Jon It seems to me that the asker believes that concurrency is simple. Just change global to local and it's all good. Or similar. I think asker is simply wrong to reject the need to understand what their program does.

Comment: @David Heffernan your position holds in the case that concurrency => OS threads and in the general case that plugging inadequately understood libraries together leads to sorrow. My view is that concurrency need not imply threads and that understanding an api instead of the code is broadly the point of a library. I suspect we only disagree about how to advise the OP.

Comment: @JonChesterfield +1 for "concurrency need not imply threads" and ''understanding an api instead of the code is broadly the point of a library".

Comment: We all agree that understanding is the key. That's what I've been saying from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Short of fixing code you can't.

You may be able to run code as separate parallel processes (assuming library does not share OS level objects like hard-coded file locations) or even separate computers.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I want to run it concurrently to improve the throughput. How can I do that?

There is no magic bullet. You cannot blindly follow a simple rule and transform the code so that it supports concurrent execution.

You need to understand the code from the point of view of concurrency, and then change it to support concurrency, if that is needed. Or even simply follow the concurrency rules in the way you use the library.

This could mean protecting shared data access with mutexes. Or replacing shared data with separated data. Or there could be combinations of these approaches. Or many other possible techniques.

The bottom line is that it depends on the code, and you will have to gain a deep understanding of it.

In an edit to the question you state that you don't want any serialization because you want as much concurrency as possible, and that you don't want to modify the libraries. These expectations are unrealistic. Concurrency is not something that can be grafted onto arbitrary code by waving a magic wand over it. I know that you don't want to accept my point of view, but I think that eventually you will come to realise that concurrency is hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably hack it into multiple threads by writing __thread or thread_local in front of all the static variables. That'll stop the threads corrupting each other, but it's not pretty. You still need a safe way to pass data between the threads of course.

Better is to spawn N instances of the program using fork and handle passing data between them using a (posix) message queue or sockets as you prefer.

Safest and probably easiest is to run N copies of the program, all on different input files.

Best but most expensive is to update the code to be correctly and elegantly thread safe - no mutable global variables, no static variables.

(thread__local vs __thread depends on your compiler and whether you're compiling the C library as C++ or as C)

Comment: I have considered thread local. But I'm not sure if it can become thread-safe by simply changing all the file static variables to thread local, even suppose no global variables exist.

Comment: You'd have to find every global and static variable, and there's no automated way I know of to do that aside from writing a customised compiler. Multiple processes is a better plan.

Comment: @duleshi Nobody can tell you whether or not unknown code will be threadsafe when changed in some general way, without knowledge of both the library being modified, or indeed your code that consumes the library. I appreciate that you want a simple solution, who doesn't? But usually there is no simple solution to problems like yours. Usually you have to gain deep understanding. Concurrency is hard.

Comment: @Jon Are you claiming that multiple processes is the best solution for all concurrency problems? Or just for this one?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I never think concurrency is simple. Thank you very much for being patience and spend so much time on this question. But one problem I recently find on some experts with very high reputations like you is that you tend to suppose the asker limit the basics on the field he asks, hence you don't fully understand the asker's question. I hava multi-threading experience on Java before. If you asked me the same question as my first comment on this answer, I will probably answer 'no, it's not safe'. I asked like that because 1) the answer mentioned it. 2) my comment is not that formal

Comment: Sharing process address space (the common meaning of thread) is an efficiency optimisation. It's effective but difficult to write correctly. I like shared-nothing concurrency at the application layer because the alternatives cost significantly more.

Comment: My view is that you are wrong to look for a silver bullet, magic wand to make your program concurrent. My view is that your question edit rules out doing the one thing that you surely need to do. You know my view. You don't agree. You hold out hope that the silver bullet exists. It's fine for us to disagree.

Comment: @Jon This is my point. It's never as simple as "X is the best way to solve Y" if Y is unknown. As it is.